# Where are orbitals located in an atom?

Tags: orbitals, atomic-structure

I am having trouble understanding what are the orbitals. Till now what I have understood, I have depicted in this diagram.

[image: Position of orbitals in an atom w.r.t orbits]

Is the diagram correct?? If not, what should be the corrections?

Answer (score 5):

An orbital is sometimes thought of a possible region where you can find an electron inside an atom. We know for sure that an electron lies inside this region, but we cannot pinpoint the location of an electron inside of this orbital. This is because of [Heisenberg's uncertainty principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle), which states that you simply cannot know both the position and the momentum of a particle with complete certainty.

Now in the model that you have drawn, you have shown the electron as a particle which means you are sticking with [Bohr's model of an atom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr_model) and therefore, it does not make much sense to talk about 'orbitals' per se. Now, where do orbitals come in? Orbitals come in when you accept an electron's [dual nature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave%E2%80%93particle_duality). That is, you accept that an electron can act as both wave and particle depending on the given circumstances. The most significant contribution to this new model of an atom was given by [Erwin Schrödinger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erwin_Schr%C3%B6dinger), who came up with the celebrated Schrödinger equation:

$$-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m_\mathrm{e}}\left(
\frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial x^2} + 
\frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial y^2} + 
\frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial z^2}
\right) + V\psi = E\psi.$$

The atomic orbitals are technically the wavefunctions $\psi$, obtained by solving this equation. In the course of solving it, you can derive three out of four quantum numbers for the electron. These are $n$ or the principal quantum number, $\ell$ or the angular momentum quantum number, and $m$ or the magnetic quantum number. These sort of describe the orbital of an electron. $n$ gives what we know as the shell number of the electron, most often labelled as numbers starting from $1$. $l$ gives what we know as the subshells. An electron can be in the following subshells: s, p, d, f (for all the elements we have till now). $m$ is used to label the individual orbitals within a subshell. For example, the s subshell has only 1 orbital, the p subshell has 3 orbitals, the d subshell has 5 orbitals, and the f subshell has 7 orbitals. Each solution $\psi$, and hence each atomic orbital, corresponds to one combination of $(n, \ell, m)$.

The fourth quantum number, which is not derived from Schrodinger's wave equation is the spin quantum number, $m_s$. This quantum number basically defines the spin of an electron in order to follow the [Pauli exclusion principle.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_exclusion_principle) If you are more interested in how these electrons decide their quantum numbers, check that out and also the [Aufbau principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aufbau_principle) and also [Hund's rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hund%27s_rules). So to give you an idea of how the actual picture of an atom might look like:

[image: an image of an atom showing the 1s and 2s subshells.]

This image only shows the 1s and 2s subshells, now if we take a look at one 2p subshell, it would look as follows:

[image: an image of the 2p_z subshell]

This is a $2p_z$ subshell, that is, this p subshell aligns itself along the $z$-axis. Follow [this link](https://www.falstad.com/qmatom/) to use the simulation for yourself.

What you can see in these images, the coloured portions, are the subshells, that is, where the electrons can be. For example, in the first image, you see 2 subshells, the 1s and the 2s subshell and each subshell can contain two electrons, so in the first image, the total number of electrons you see are 4 electrons which can exist anywhere inside the coloured region (you simply cannot pinpoint a particular location as it would be against Heisenberg's uncertainty principle), the same is the case with the second image where the $2p_z$ subshell is shown. This again contains two electrons and they can be located anywhere. Now a real atom is a mixture of all these shells, subshells, and orbitals where the electrons can be located each with a spin to satisfy the Pauli exclusion principle. I hope that clarifies your question and hopefully, I have been able to provide with some more knowledge/resources to understand the topic further.

One interesting note: If I have not already confused you enough, listen to this: In actuality, there is nothing known as 'shells' and 'subshells' all we have are the orbitals. The shells are a simple way to represent the size of these orbitals, the subshells are a way to represent the shape of the orbitals, and the magnetic quantum number (m) is a way to represent the orientation of these orbitals.

Comment: Magnetic quantum number can be represented by $m_l$ and spin quantum number as $m_s$

Comment: (1) An orbital is not a region; it is a wavefunction. (2) The magnetic quantum number does not take the values 1, 3, 5, 7... it is permitted to take integer values between $-\ell$ and $+\ell$ inclusive. The *total number of permitted $m$-values* is equal to 1, 3, 5, 7... but the *values of $m$ itself* aren't that. (3) Nobody really uses KLMN for shells, except for spectroscopists sometimes. You yourself wrote about the 1s orbital, not Ks orbital. Anyway, I corrected these and other (fairly small) technical inaccuracies in my edit.

Comment: @orthocresol I have said in some old answers/comments the orbital has several meanings: orbital(1)= wave function, orbital(2)=el. quantum state related to (1), orbital(3)=3D region, related to (1,2) covering probable occurance of el. according to the integral probability and boundary pr. density. // Is it wrong ?

Comment: @Poutnik Hmm, I wouldn't say it's entirely wrong. Going by technical correctness, the orbital is the wavefunction. The 3D region, or the isosurface is just a representation of the 3D function (this depiction is necessarily limited by the fact that we can't actually draw 3D functions). It's a bit like a function $f(x) = x^2$ vs a graph of the parabola $y = x^2$; the former is a function, the latter is a depiction. In this 1D case the depiction is entirely faithful so one might possibly argue they're the same thing. In the 3D case not so much.

Comment: @Poutnik I have to say, I remember that answer of yours and I'm pretty sure I upvoted it. Reason is because it explains the link going from wavefunction to isosurface. That's the real underlying science and if that's explained correctly, then I probably don't really care so much about what an orbital "is" or "isn't", because the facts are there and the reader may use critical thinking. However, here, the link is not drawn (presumably for simplicity) and so I think it becomes more dangerous to say that an orbital is an area -- that may be indirectly true but it's not explained why this is true.

Comment: @orthocresol I see and agree with your late reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

First, [electrons do not actually "orbit" the nucleus](https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/dont-electrons-crash-nucleus-atoms/), because if they were whirling around in circles, they would radiate electromagnetic energy and "fall" into the nucleus.

While you might draw a circle on paper as an illustration, the probability of finding an electron is better [viewed as a fuzzy cotton ball](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/The-fuzzy-position-of-the-electron-relative-to-the-proton-in-various-stationary-states-of_fig1_225119532), stretched into different shapes for different orbitals.

So there's no harm in drawing illustrations of orbits as circles, don't be confused into thinking the electrons follow circles, or [circles with planetary epicycles](https://www.spitzinc.com/blog/epicycles-and-discovering-bad-theories/), in an atom

Answer (score -3):

Orbitals are centred around the nucleus. If an atom has many orbitals, either one orbital is bigger than the others or they overlap.

Moreover, the orbitals are an area where an electron is ***most likely*** to be in. You can, like your prototype, draw a dashed line along the orbital.

Comment: Orbital is not an area.